# What is the difference between these Kotlin compiler flags?

Tags: kotlin, compiler-flags

For some time Kotlin allowed to set `kotlin.incremental=true` and since 1.1.2 there is also `kotlin.compiler.incremental=true`.

I would like to know what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Alexey Tsvetkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2065811/alexey-tsvetkov) `kotlin.compiler.incremental` is maven only, and it is named similar to other maven options.

Answer (score 2):

`kotlin.compiler.incremental` is a property, which can be set in a maven project to enable incremental kotlin compilation by default.

It is set in the properties block in `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project>
    ...
    <properties>
        <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
    </properties>
    ...
</project>
```

Or you can pass this option with the command line argument:

```
mvn install -Dkotlin.compiler.incremental=true
```

Answer (score 1):

It is all about maven build logic. Look here for more details: [Maven Incremental Build](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2016/08/12/maven-incremental-module-build/)